# What is the correct URL pattern to connect DB2 RDBMS Type 4 DB

Tags: spring, db2

What is the correct URL pattern to connect DB2 RDBMS Type 4 DB

Comment: first thing : you should try with a more recent version. 1.2.4.RELEASE is old.

Comment: @davidxxx I need to use 1.2.4 as this is existing application.

Comment: I don't know Spring Boot but surely later versions are backward compatible, aren't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the exception message `Failure in loading native library db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`.
The answer could be found in [IBM Support](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21419978).

Appearly, your JDBC url is **type 2** which may look like **jdbc:db2:DB_NAME**. In this mode, JDBC driver connect to database by extra library. These files could be accquired by installing DB2 client (or server).

Changing the JDBC url to **type 4** is another workaround. The offical support site offer [more detail about URL format](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052342.html).

Comment: I have added // in my URL string after which its referred type 4 driver.Also I need to use db2jcc4.9.7.jar as my dependency.Thansk for your help.